# HOMO and LUMO Conjugated System

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

> The particle on a ring is a useful model for the motion of electrons around the porphine ring, the conjugated macrocycle that forms the structural basis of the heme group and the chlorophylls. We may treat the group as a circular ring of radius $\pu{440 pm}$, with 20 electrons in the conjugated system moving along the perimeter of the ring. Assume that in the ground state of the molecule quantized each level is occupied by two electrons.
> (a) Calculate the energy and angular momentum of an electron in the highest occupied level.
> (b) Calculate the frequency of radiation that can induce a transition between the highest occupied and lowest unoccupied levels. 
> [image: Porphine]

How do you calculate HOMO and LUMO given that 20 $\pi$ electrons exist? Writing the electron configuration of the ground state molecule seems too lengthy.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to look at the molecule at all, except to count the number of pi electrons, which you've already done. You only need the solutions to the particle on a ring system. It's not asking you to calculate the HOMO and the LUMO of the molecule, it's asking you to calculate the $n$-th and $(n+1)$-th stationary state of the particle on a ring.

Comment: if I want to use the following formula, then I need to know the quantum number of rotational motion. It is given that with 22 pi electrons it is supposedly five, but I do not know where this value came from.

Comment: Do you know the particle on a ring? And how to solve the Schrodinger equation to get the states and energies for that particular system?